# Render problem with GPU compute RX480

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

It seems that I have a problem with my rendering with cycles :

When I select GPU Compute, rendering becomes very laggy, everything is delayed, it's not possible to work with, also on basics scenes.

### When I switch to CPU everything comes instant and really working well. No delay, no lag or everything.

I'm using 4690k and AMD RX480.
I just updated my AMD drivers.

Any idea of from where this problem comes from?

Comment: Have you set the cycles compute device in the Blender Preferences?

Comment: Hi, yes of course :)